# Comment or uncomment some code automatically after publish in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have some code in my project that I make comment or uncomment when I want to publish, But I have to do that manually.
Is there a way to make comment or uncomment some code automatically after I published the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way for that. I used this code:

```
#if DEBUG  
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");  
#endif
```

The code between `#if` and `#endif` only execute in debug mode.

[read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)